# Transformation between standardized to non-standardized in matrix form

Tags: r, matrix, transform, inverse

Perhaps someone can tell me where I am wrong with the below code.  I'm trying to standardize a variable set and then transform it back into its original state.  However, it seems as if I have errors on every other row.

```
set.seed(1234)
trash = matrix(runif(10), ncol = 2)
trashc = apply(trash, 2, function(x) x - mean(x))
trashstd = diag(1/sqrt(diag(cov(trashc))))
trashstdr = as.matrix(trashc) %*% trashstd
tmptrash = trashstdr %*% solve(trashstd)
tmptrash = tmptrash + colMeans(trash)

Results from transformation:
tmptrash
#          [,1]      [,2]
#[1,] 0.1137034 0.6403106
#[2,] 0.4689233 0.1628719
#[3,] 0.6092747 0.2325505
#[4,] 0.4700033 0.8194599
#[5,] 0.8609154 0.5142511

Original set:
trash
#          [,1]        [,2]
#[1,] 0.1137034 0.640310605
#[2,] 0.6222994 0.009495756
#[3,] 0.6092747 0.232550506
#[4,] 0.6233794 0.666083758
#[5,] 0.8609154 0.514251141
```

Comment: The last line should be `tmptrash = t(t(tmptrash) + colMeans(trash))`

Comment: thanks @DarrenTsai I completely missed that